# Android Relative Layout In TableRow followed by TableRow with Linear Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, tablelayout, tablerow

I am currently working on an Android application to be run on Android 6.  I am completely new to Android development but have a little bit of WPF experience so I thought the XML would be similar.  The following is what I would like the view to look like:

[image]

This is the XML I currently have to solve this problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_guimain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:weightSum="2"
    tools:context="indoorpilot.indoorpilot.GUIMain">
    <TableRow>
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent">-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Building Label"/>
    </TableRow>


    <TableRow>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/mclaurysecondfloor"
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/presence_online"
                android:="@+id/markerImage"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle">
            <Button
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/contextual_info"
                android:onClick="ShowContextualInformation"/>
            <Button
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/scan_button"
                android:onClick="SetRSSIDistanceValues"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Which is working fine on a large device (tablet) but it does not show properly in the Android Studio View Renderer OR on a phone of any sorts.  The buttons are not shown as the TableRow containing the RelativeLayout ends up taking up the entire screen...

Comment: Instead of `TableLayout` as parent, use `RelativeLayout`. and align your top row to parent and bottom row to parent bottom. `RelativeLayout` provides you alignment of all sorts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this outside android studio, but may help you, if you need I can edit for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_guimain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:weightSum="2"
    tools:context="indoorpilot.indoorpilot.GUIMain">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Building Label"/>



        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_above="@+id/buttons_container"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/mclaurysecondfloor"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/presence_online"
            android:id="@+id/markerImage"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/buttons_container"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle">
        <Button
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/contextual_info"
            android:onClick="ShowContextualInformation"/>
        <Button
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/scan_button"
            android:onClick="SetRSSIDistanceValues"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

You don't need a `TableLayout`. What you need is a `RelativeLayout` that has one `TextView` at the top, two `ImageView`s below, and a `LinearLayout` containing the two buttons at the bottom of your view. You may need a `ScrollView` containing this `RelativeLayout` for smaller screen sizes.